# called object not a function c

Tags: c, pointers, copy-constructor

Good morning SO- this ones been cooking my noodle for a bit (also, it's very hard to google about the c programming language I've noticed...)

```
void prepareFrames(PDouble prep){
  int gap = prep->gap;
  printf("Gap is %d\n", gap);
  prep->intFrames = (PFrame*)malloc(gap*sizeof(PFrame));
  PFrame copyFrame = prep->first;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < gap; i++){
    prep->intFrames[i] = (PFrame)malloc(sizeof(Frame));
    copyFrame(prep->intFrames[i], prep->first, i);          //LINE 189
  }
}

void copyFrame(PFrame new, PFrame copy, int num){
  new->sequence = copy->sequence;
  new->evaluatedFrame = copy->evaluatedFrame + num;
  new->numBoxes = copy->numBoxes;
  new->boxes = (PBox*)malloc(copy->numBoxes*sizeof(PBox));
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < copy->numBoxes; i++){
    PBox old = copy->boxes[i];
    new->boxes[i] = (PBox)malloc(sizeof(Box));
    copyBox(new->boxes[i], old);
  }
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
error: called object ‘copyFrame’ is not a function
```

The prototypes match the definition. What gives?

Comment: You have two things that are called `copyFrame` in that context. Try renaming  `PFrame copyFrame`.

Comment: You should turn on some [compiler warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) :) at least `-Wshadow` if using gcc. I also recommend `-Wall`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've redefined `copyFrame` in that local scope:

```
PFrame copyFrame = prep->first;
```

Comment: Never would have guessed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a local variabe named copyFrame: `PFrame copyFrame = prep->first;` Unless PFrame is defined by

```
typedef void (*PFrame)(PFrame new, PFrame copy, int num);
```

I don't see how it should ever compile. Otherwise, you don't even use that `copyFrame` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable named copyFrame which is conflicting with your function name.

Rename `PFrame copyFrame` to something else and it should work.