# rename() not working in a C program compiled using Dev C++

Tags: c, rename, ntfs, file-rename, dev-c++

I would like to write a program in C that can rename a number of files under MS Win 7 environment (NTFS file system). Hence the `rename()` function seems to be a natural choice. However, when I write the following in Dev-C++ (but naming the source file as .c):

```
rename(name1, name2);
```

Compiling the file gives me the error:

```
[Error] called object 'rename' is not a function
```

I have already added `<stdio.h>` as the header. Is there anything I am missing?

The source code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 50
#define MAX 49

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int i, rename;
    char name1[25], name2[25];

    srand(time(NULL));
    rename = 0;

    p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
       p[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (p[i] == 0) {
            printf ("** ", i);
            sprintf(name1, "abc%d.jpg", i);
            sprintf(name2, "abct.jpg");
            rename(name1, name2);
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is that the *complete* error? You have included the proper header files?

Comment: Show you your full code, please. Then we can say more.

Comment: And you expect us to fix your error by clairvoyance-over-tcp/ip? Post your code!

Comment: assuming that the original file name exists (you could use stat() to determine that detail).  Then use something like: char buffer[100] = {'\0'}; sprintf( buffer, "rename %s %s\n", oldName, newName);  system( buffer );  assuming that your OS uses 'rename' to change the name of a file and assuming that your program has the priviledge to change the name of the specific file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have some variables named with `rename`, that's why compiler gives `called object 'rename' is not a function`. Check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949982/called-object-not-a-function-c). As said in the comment, please give more about your code.

Comment: This indeed seems to be the problem, now that we have seen the code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have used a variable called `rename`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You have declared a variable called `rename`. This is confusing the compiler.

```
int i, rename;
```

I suggest you, erm, rename it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char filename[101], newfilename[101];

    printf("Please type in name of file to be changed : \n");
    scanf("%s", &filename); /* Get the filename from the keyboard) */

    printf("You have choosen to rename %s.\nPlease type the new name of the file : \n", filename);
    scanf("%s", &newfilename); /* Get the new filename from the keyboard) */

    if (rename(filename, newfilename) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s has been renamed to %s.\n", filename, newfilename);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error renaming %s.\n", filename);
    }
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");

    return 0;
}
```